# Django rest framework - how to make case insensitive viewset search

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to enable case insensitive search in rest framework's viewsets?

For example, assuming Post model has a tag. All links below should find the same tag content, right now they are case sensitive and try to search for different values:

1. /posts/tag=AbcDef
2. /posts/tag=abcdef
3. /posts/tag=AbcdeF

**views.py**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: can you show your `urls.py`?

Comment: You may consider using a case-insensitive data type for this column like `CITEXT`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you have field called **tag** in **Post** model and your search url is of the form:

```
/posts/?tag=AbcDef
```

You can do case sensitive search like:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet): 
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        keyword = self.request.query_params.get('tag', '')
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(tag__iexact=keyword)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 8):

Did you look into using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter ? That does case-insensitive searching by default.